# Drawing a Grid for placement in 3D space

Tags: c#, winforms, visualization

Hello more advanced coders,

I am having great difficulty finding answers to my questions as unfortunately, being self taught I have no clue whatsoever what the proper terminology is for the things I'm doing. As a result this could be a more difficult to answer question than it needs to be. Apologies in advance.

I am cobbling together a little game as a vanity project in which the player does spaceship stuff.

I have a property called Bounding_Dimensions_Property

```
using System;

namespace Madness_In_Space
{
    public class Bounding_Dimensions_Property
    {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    public Bounding_Dimensions_Property (int xx, int yy, int zz)
    {
        this.x = xx;
        this.y = yy;
        this.z = zz;
    }
}
```

}

This describes a grid of possible points in which to place a room.

I wish to visualise the grid on a windows form as an orthographic plan and section and an isometric view (just for pretties).

---

**Actual Question**

What methods are there available to me, to take my x,y,z values and draw a grid on a windows form that has "x" length and "y" width, with a line for each whole number value between "x" or "y" and 0? I also wish to do the same for a "y" and "z" grid. I would like to use a method that allows me to take each cube within the grid and set it as "occupied" or "vacant". I was toying with the idea of using a multidimensional array/hashtable to hold the occupancy information, but I don't know if that's sensible.

---

I have further questions but first I'll make sure this one isn't rejected.

Apologies again if I'm spouting gibberish - which it appears I am.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: What's your *actual* question here?

Comment: Hmmmm I'd better edit the post - good point.

Comment: Is this, 'How do you suggest I visualise my 3D grid' or 'How do I draw a 3D grid on a form' or 'How should I record data for a 3D grid'?

Comment: How do you suggest I visualise my 3D grid please.

Comment: I should probably clarify again, I definitely want to visualise it as an orthographic projection.

Comment: @the_scoundrel_M I strongly suggest WPF instead of winforms if you need 3D support. winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anymore, and it does not have any kind of 3D support. WPF has built in 3D support plus hardware acceleration, which will be needed in your case. Otherwise go straight to XNA or pure DirectX or OpenGL for this. winforms is definitely not an option for this.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I did some more reading and I *think* that my best bet is to instantiate a bitmap and draw to that using the draw commands.

I will then use the values in the coordinates I'm working from, divide the width/height of the bitmap by the required number of lines, take the lower figure of the two and draw straight lines across the bitmap at that interval.

Once it works I'll come back and post code so you don't have to put up with my prose description.